# $W_{total}=W_{external}+W_{by, gas}=0?$

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, work, gas

Consider pushing a closed piston filled with air inwards with an external force which exerts a pressure of magnitude $p$ onto the syringe.

If we know that $$\delta W_{EXT}=-p dV$$
and by definition
$$\delta W_{by,gas}=pdV$$
and equivalently
$$\delta W_{on,gas}=- pdV$$ 
Do these equations imply that

$$W_{on,gas}=W_{EXT}$$

so that $$W_{TOT}=W_{EXT}+W_{by,gas}=0$$
may seem to be a stupid one but I need to check my understanding of basic thermodynamics.

Comment: If the inside and outside are separated by a massless piston, then the total work done on the piston is zero.  But this is not the work done on- or by the gas.  The work done by the gas, as you indicated, is pdV.

Comment: Are you trying to prove that $W_{\text{total}}=W_{\text{external}}+W_{\text{by  gas}}$ using $\delta W=-pdV$ ?

Comment: @ Electroelf Yes